# Proper Error throwing and handling to abort a mongoose transaction

Tags: node.js, mongoose, transactions

I'm still pretty new to Node and mongoose and I'm trying to implement transactions for incoming orders in my node server to handle 4 processes and to abort if any of them should fail, but app crashes with an `Unhandled 'error' event` error.
The sequence of operations is:

1. update product sold/available quantities
2. get shop's Stripe details
3. get customers Stripe details
4. place the order

If at point 3 the customer doesn't have a saved default payment method I just send a response that in the client app will prompt user to register one, and throw an Error that should be catch and abort the transaction reverting product sold/available quantities to previous values.
So for the transaction I'm the try{} catch{} finally{} scopes as in mongoose docs.
The problem is that when I throw the `new Error('User has not registered a default_Method');` app crashes with an `Unhandled 'error' event` error so I'm not trowing/handling errors properly and/or using transactions API properly.

Can you spot what I'm doing wrong?
Many thanks.

```
exports.createOrder = async (req, res) => {

    const { productIdList, productPromotionList, customerId, shopId } = req.body;

    console.log('createOreder req.body is : ', req.body);
    var amount = 0.00;
    var stripeAccountId = '';
    var stripeCustomerId = '';
    var receiptEmail = '';
    var defaultSource = '';
    const session = await Order.startSession();
    session.startTransaction();

    // modify product records
    const ids = productIdList;
    const isPromotion = productPromotionList;
    for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
        if (isPromotion[i] == false) {
            await Product.findByIdAndUpdate(
                ids[i],
                {
                    $inc: { soldQuantity: 1, availableQuantity: -1 },
                },
                { new: true },
                function (err, result) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log('Mongoose Order.createOrder / Product.update error: ', err);

                        res.status(503).send({ error: "Internal error." });
                        session.abortTransaction();
                        return;
                    }

                    console.log('Mongoose Order.createOrder / Product.update Inventory updated successfully for product:', result);
                });
        } else {
            await Promotion.findByIdAndUpdate(
                ids[i],
                {
                    $inc: { soldQuantity: 1, availableQuantity: -1 },
                },
                { new: true },
                function (err, result) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log('Mongoose Order.createOrder / Promotion.update error: ', err);
                        res.status(503).send({ error: "Internal error." });
                        session.abortTransaction();
                        return;
                    }

                    console.log('Mongoose Order.createOrder / Promotion.update Inventory updated successfully for promotion:', result);
                });
        }

    }

    // get customer stipe id
    await Shop.findById(
        shopId,
        function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('Mongoose createOrder / Shop.findById error: ', err);
                res.status(503).send({ error: "Internal error." });
                session.abortTransaction();
                return;
            }
            if (result != null) {
                console.log("Mongoose createOrder / Shop.findById: ", result);
                if (result.stripeDetails) {
                    stripeAccountId = result.stripeDetails.id;
                } else {
                    console.log('Mongoose createOrder / Shop.findById: shop has no stripe id');
                    res.status(503).send({ error: "Internal error." });
                    session.abortTransaction();
                    return;
                }

            } else {
                console.log("Mongoose createOrder / Shop.findById: Shop not found");
                res.status(404).send({ error: "Shop not found." });
                session.abortTransaction();
                return;
            }
        }

    );

    // get customer stripe credentials 

    await User.findById(
        customerId,
        function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('Mongoose createOrder / User.findOneById error: ', err);
                res.status(503).send({ error: "Internal error." });
                throw err;
                return;
            }
            if (result != null) {
                console.log("Mongoose createOrder / User.findOneById: ", result);

                if (result.stripeDetails) {
                    stripeCustomerId = result.stripeDetails.id;

                } else {
                    console.log('Mongoose createOrder / User.findOneById: User has no stripe id');
                    res.status(404).send({ message: "User has no stripe id" });
                    session.abortTransaction();
                    return;
                }
                // check if user has registered a pyment_method
                if (result.stripeDetails.default_source != null) {
                    defaultSource = result.stripeDetails.default_source;
                    receiptEmail = result.stripeDetails.email;

                } else {
                    console.log('Mongoose createOrder / User.findOneById: User has not registered a default_Method');
                    res.status(402).send({ message: "Stripe: Default Payment Required" });

                    /// unhandled error and app crashes
                    session.abortTransaction();
                    return;
                }

            } else {
                console.log('Mongoose createOrder / User.findOneById: User not found');
                res.status(404).send({ error: "User not found." });
                session.abortTransaction();
                return;
            }
        }

    ).catch((e) => {

        console.log('User.findById .catch() error is :', e)
    });

    /// save order + create stripe payment
    await Order.create(
        req.body,
        function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('Mongoose createOrder error:  Order.create', error);
                res.statut(503).send({ error: "Internal error" });
                session.abortTransaction();
                return;
            }

            /// create charge/payment

            // stripe.paymentIntents.create({
            //     customer: stripeCustomerId,
            //     receipt_email: receiptEmail,
            //     account: stripeAccountId,
            //     default_source: defaultSource,
            //     confirm: true,
            //     setup_future_usage: "on_session",// makes it pay in one go
            //     amount: amount,
            //     application_fee_amount: (amount * 0.13) + 25,
            //     currency: "eur",
            //     paymentMethods: ["card"],
            //     description: `Payment for order: ${result.id}`,
            //     on_behalf_of: stripeCustomerId,

            // })
            //     .then(paymentIntent => {
            //         console.log('Mongoose createOrder stripe paymentIntent: ', paymentIntent);
            //         result.set('stripePayment', paymentIntent);
            //         result.save();
            //     })
            //     .catch(error => {
            //         console.log('Mongoose createOrder stripe paymentIntent error: ', error);
            //     });
            console.log('Mongoose createOrder: ', result);
            res.status(200).send({
                message: "Order created successfully!",
                data: result
            });

        });

    await session.commitTransaction();

    session.endSession();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem was that I didn't yet convert my local MongoDB instance to be a replica set, so that was the first thing to fix.
Then I implemented `try{}catch{}finally{}` statements to handle errors and
calls of `await session.commitTransaction();` and `session.endSession();` depending on the session state, as calling `abortTransaction()` takes session out of inTransaction state.
I will change the business logic dough and check  User and Customer payment requirements and only then start the transaction with only Product and Order schemas if they are met, to save the server quite a bit of operation.

So here is the code should help others struggling with mongo transactions:

```
exports.createOrder = async (req, res) => {

    const { productIdList, productPromotionList, customerId, shopId } = req.body;

    console.log('createOreder req.body is : ', req.body);
    var amount = 0.00;
    var stripeAccountId = '';
    var stripeCustomerId = '';
    var receiptEmail = '';
    var defaultSource = '';
    const session = await Order.startSession();
    session.startTransaction();

    try {
        /// test error
        // throw Error('Test error to see if calling session.endSession() in cath{} crashes the app.');


        // modify product records
        const ids = productIdList;
        const isPromotion = productPromotionList;
        for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
            if (isPromotion[i] == false) {
                const product = await Product.findByIdAndUpdate(
                    ids[i],
                    {
                        $inc: { soldQuantity: 1, availableQuantity: -1 },
                    },
                    { session: session },
                    function (err, result) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log('Mongoose Order.createOrder / Product.update error: ', err);
                            res.status(503).send({ error: "Internal error." });
                            session.abortTransaction();
                            return;
                        }

                        console.log('Mongoose Order.createOrder / Product.update Inventory updated successfully for product:', result);
                    });
            } else {
                const promotion = await Promotion.findByIdAndUpdate(
                    ids[i],
                    {
                        $inc: { soldQuantity: 1, availableQuantity: -1 },
                    },
                    { session: session },
                    function (err, result) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log('Mongoose Order.createOrder / Promotion.update error: ', err);
                            res.status(503).send({ error: "Internal error." });
                            session.abortTransaction();
                            return;
                        }

                        console.log('Mongoose Order.createOrder / Promotion.update Inventory updated successfully for promotion:', result);
                    });
            }

        }

        ///get customer stipe id 
        ///  if passing the session to the options it will throw
        ///    Error: ClientSession cannot be serialized to BSON.

        const shop = await Shop.findById(
            shopId,
            // { session: session }, 
            function (err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('Mongoose createOrder / Shop.findById error: ', err);
                    res.status(503).send({ error: "Internal error." });
                    session.abortTransaction();
                    return;
                }
                if (result != null) {
                    console.log("Mongoose createOrder / Shop.findById: ", result);
                    if (result.stripeDetails != null) {
                        stripeAccountId = result.stripeDetails['id'];
                    } else {
                        console.log('Mongoose createOrder / Shop.findById: shop has no stripe id');
                        res.status(503).send({ error: "Internal error." });
                        session.abortTransaction();
                        return;
                    }

                } else {
                    console.log("Mongoose createOrder / Shop.findById: Shop not found");
                    res.status(404).send({ error: "Shop not found." });
                    session.abortTransaction();
                    return;
                }
            }

        );

        // ////get customer stripe credentials 

        const user = await User.findById(
            customerId,
            function (err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('Mongoose createOrder / User.findOneById error: ', err);
                    res.status(503).send({ error: "Internal error." });
                    session.abortTransaction();
                    return;
                }
                if (result != null) {
                    console.log("Mongoose createOrder / User.findOneById: ", result);

                    if (result.stripeDetails) {
                        stripeCustomerId = result.stripeDetails['id'];

                    } else {
                        console.log('Mongoose createOrder / User.findOneById: User has no stripe id');
                        res.status(404).send({ message: "User has no stripe id" });
                        session.abortTransaction();
                        return;
                    }
                    //check if user has registered a pyment_method
                    if (result.stripeDetails['default_source'] != null) {
                        defaultSource = result.stripeDetails['default_source'];
                        receiptEmail = result.stripeDetails['email'];

                    } else {
                        console.log('Mongoose createOrder / User.findOneById: User has not registered a default_Method');
                        res.status(402).send({ message: "Stripe: Default Payment Required" });

                        session.abortTransaction();
                        return;
                    }

                } else {
                    console.log('Mongoose createOrder / User.findOneById: User not found');
                    res.status(404).send({ error: "User not found." });
                    session.abortTransaction();
                    return;
                }
            }

        );

        //// save order + create stripe payment
        const order = await Order.create(
            req.body,
            { session: session },
            function (err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('Mongoose createOrder error:  Order.create', error);
                    res.statut(503).send({ error: "Internal error" });
                    session.abortTransaction();
                    return;
                }

                /////// create charge/payment

                // stripe.paymentIntents.create({
                //     customer: stripeCustomerId,
                //     receipt_email: receiptEmail,
                //     account: stripeAccountId,
                //     default_source: defaultSource,
                //     confirm: true,
                //     setup_future_usage: "on_session",// makes it pay in one go
                //     amount: amount,
                //     application_fee_amount: (amount * 0.13) + 25,
                //     currency: "eur",
                //     paymentMethods: ["card"],
                //     description: `Payment for order: ${result.id}`,
                //     on_behalf_of: stripeCustomerId,

                // })
                // .then(paymentIntent => {
                //     console.log('Mongoose createOrder stripe paymentIntent: ', paymentIntent);
                //     result.set('stripePayment', paymentIntent);
                //     result.save();
                // })
                // .catch(error => {
                //     console.log('Mongoose createOrder stripe paymentIntent error: ', error);
                // res.statut(503).send({ error: "Payment processing error" });
                // session.abortTransaction();
                // });
                console.log('Mongoose createOrder: ', result);
                res.status(200).send({
                    message: "Order created successfully!",
                    data: result
                });

            });



    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log('Transaction error is:', error);
        await session.abortTransaction();
        session.endSession();
        res.status(503).send({ error: "Internal error." });
        // throw error; 
    }
    finally {

        if (session.inTransaction == true) {

            console.log('committing session');
            await session.commitTransaction();
            console.log('ending session');
            // if called here the app won`t crash
            session.endSession();
        } else {
            console.log('session was aborted');

            /// if endSession() get called here app crashes with 
            /// error: MongoError: Attempted illegal state transition from [TRANSACTION_ABORTED] to [TRANSACTION_ABORTED]
            /// because session is not in transaction state
            // session.endSession(); 
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: `session.inTransaction == true` is always going to be true since inTransaction is a function on session. That line in the finally block should be `if(session.inTransaction()) {`.

Comment: Indeed, i never updated the answer. Thank you very much for pointing it out